# expo wont start after switching wsl1 to wsl2

Tags: expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I tried to run `expo start` or `yarn start` and the console threw an error. On wsl1 it is working fine, it shows the QR code. However, I have to switch to wsl2 to set up mysql for my local server and now expo is not starting.
Also sometimes the QR code shows up but when I try to open the app in my device, the same error shows up.

```
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
    at _waitForRunningAsync (/home/kevsmercs/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startLegacyReactNativeServerAsync.ts:344:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I think the problem here is expo itself. I tried to I check the developer tools url, the site cant be reached. I also tried to check my account using `expo login` and this error shows up

```
Fetching the user profile failed
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14)
```

jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler. Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project. Error: Watchman error: query failed: synchronization failed: Connection timed out. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.

```
I tried multiple fixes but no luck.
 1. set `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME` to my ip using `export`
 2. delete `.expo` from root of project and run `expo start -c`
 3. turn off windows defender and firewall
 4. update `expo-cli` to latest (4.4.1)
 5. restart laptop
```

Answer (score 1):

[Maybe this GitHub issue describes your problem and the workaround?](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/949)

> This can usually happen when publishing without ever having run expo start, also it's a good idea to run rm -rf .expo to clear your local state

> [it's listed in our common development errors](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/common-development-errors/#metro-bundler-econnrefused-12700119001)

Your latest edit shows this error message and suggested fix: `Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty` .watchmanconfig `file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.` Did you try that?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I already checked that one but it didnt work. I updated my question.

Comment: I appended to my answer

Comment: yep, I added `.watchmanconfig` to my root folder containing only `{}`. the error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888` is  showing.

Comment: That same error from my comment above also shows up when I tried to check my expo account: `expo login`

Comment: Sure sounds like whatever is supposed to be listening at port 8888 is not actually listening. OK, you configured watchman. Did you start the watchman service after configuring it?

Comment: sorry but how can i start it? I tried `watchman watch-project ./`.

Comment: That is a different question. I don't know the answer. Never used it. Please accept my answer and upvote it.